# Rake Gems Install Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am getting the following error when trying to install gems:

```
Mohammad-Azams-MacBook-Pro:awesomecats azamsharp$ sudo rake gems:install
Password:
(in /Projects/awesomecats)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gems:install'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Mohammad-Azams-MacBook-Pro:awesomecats azamsharp$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the task isn't listed in the output of `rake -T` then it isn't defined and you can't run it.

Rails 3 removed this task in favor of using `Gemfile` and [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) as the official gem installation procedure as `gems:install` was often tricky to get working properly.